# Showing that $(|\left<a, b\right>| - \epsilon)^2 \leq |\left<a, Mb\right>|^2$ for self-adjoint operator $M$ such that $||(I - M)b|| < \epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $a, b$ be $L^2$ normalized functions and $M$ be a self-adjoint pseudodifferential operator such that $||(I - M)b|| < \epsilon$ and $\sigma(M) \leq 1$ (author of the paper I am reading has not defined what $\sigma$ means, so I am assuming it is the norm of $M$).

**Edit**: Let us furthermore require that $I \neq M \neq 0$.

I am trying to show that $(|\left<a, b\right>| - \epsilon)^2 \leq |\left<a, Mb\right>|^2$, but I seem to be mathematically too immature with operator inequalities. What I have done so far is,

$|\left<a, Mb\right>|^2 = |\left<a, Mb + (I - M)b - (I - M)b\right>|^2 = |\left<a, b - (I - M)b\right>|^2 = |\left<a, b\right> - \left<a, (I - M)b\right>|^2 \geq \left(|\left<a, b\right>| - |\left<a, (I - M)b\right>|\right)^2$

where I need to relate $|\left<a, (I - M)b\right>|$ to $||(I - M)b|| < \epsilon$, but I don't know how.

Any help/tips are appreciated!

Comment: The operator $M=0$ fulfills the assumptions, but the inequality will be false in general for such $M$.

Comment: @daw I see, how much leeway would we gain by requiring that $M \neq 0$?

Comment: Inequality is false if $Mb=b$ and $a \perp b$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Good point! While it starts to sound like a start for a spaghetti argument, what if we require, in addition to $M \neq 0$, that $M \neq I$? I'm just trying to reverse engineer what the author had in mind when he stated that $\left(|\left<a, b\right>| - \epsilon\right)^2$ is a lower bound for $|\left<a, Mb\right>|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the triangular inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the assumptions, you have $$|\langle a,Mb \rangle| \ge |\langle a,b \rangle| - |\langle a,(I-M)b \rangle| 
\ge |\langle a,b \rangle| - ||a|| \times ||(I-M)b|| \ge |\langle a,b \rangle| - \epsilon.$$
Yet, you cannot square the inequality, since the right-hand side may be negative. You have just
$$|\langle a,Mb \rangle| \ge \max \big(|\langle a,b \rangle| - \epsilon,0 \big).$$